# 'Permission denied' running script on files

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, md5sum

I have a watch folder setup in Powershell to create checksums running the following batch file:

```
pushd \\server\folder
for %%a in (*.wav) do if not exist "%%a.md5" md5sum "%%a" >> "%%a.md5"
popd
```

I've found it I move files into the folder it runs okay but if I copy files into the folder I get 'permission denied' on some of the files resulting in blank checksums.  It doesn't appear to be consistent though and I can run the batch script manually from the folder without any problems.  I'm on the system as an admin (Win7). Any ideas?

EDIT:  This is the powershell script:

```
$folder = '\\server\folder' 
$filter = '*.wav' 

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green 
write-host "test"
Invoke-Item '\\server\folder\checksum.bat'
```

Comment: Are you running the script as an admin for your local machine, or for the domain?

Comment: FileSystemWatcher (I assume your using that) events may sink multiple times before the file copy is complete so "md5sum" can attempt to read a file that is in use, similarly AV products may lock a new file.  Your options are to implement a retry strategy or a TTL system that queues new files for processing at some point in the future.

Comment: I'm not a network admin so probably just the local machine.  I should have full read/write access to the server though...

Comment: I've pasted in the powershell script:- do you mind showing how I could implement a retry?  Thanks.

Comment: It can be the applocker. You try bypass  it with this technique - http://dostips.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3 . You can try also to create executable with the built-in .net compilers or to try with msbuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you aren't a domain admin you can't be certain that you don't have full access to the files on the drive.

In addition to whatever fixes are needed in your PowerShell script (sorry, can't help there), you should give yourself full access to the files.

Try this in the batch file:

```
PUSHD \\server\folder
FOR %%F IN (*.wav) DO @TAKEOWN /F "%%F"
FOR %%F IN (*.wav) DO @CACLS "%%F" /E /P <YourUsernameHere>:F
FOR %%F IN (*.wav) DO @IF NOT EXIST "%%F.md5" md5sum "%%F" >> "%%F.md5"
POPD
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm still having the same problems though so it might be the domain admin as you've suggested.